# Whatsapp requests UPnP

Tags: whatsapp, upnp

What info is taken when WhatsApp requests UPnP? Is it hacked? What does it do with UPnP? I have checked many websites but the answer is the same, that UPnP is harmful. But I want full details about what info is taken from WhatsApp.
What does it do when WhatsApp requests UPnP when the data fetched or accessed by a third party or is it hacked?

Is my private data being seen by any other person?
And what is taken by UPnP? Are there messages, or calls, video calls? What exactly is taken?

Comment: Comments in this question [Found an application (Whatsapp) initiating UPnP requests, is it something that I should worry about?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201173/found-an-application-whatsapp-initiating-upnp-requests-is-it-something-that-i) answers your question. I'll soon answer that question with specific details. TL,Dr: It is using uPnP for WhatsApp calling.

Comment: From a security standpoint, there is nothing strange and seeing UPnP does not mean that you are hacked. What WhatsApp does with UPnP is not a security question and one for the vendor.